# Angular Web Api 2 is not working with POST : 405 Method Not Allowed

Tags: c#, angular, typescript, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am using `Angular` with `asp.net Api 2` but post method is not working with Angular while it is working fine with Postman and i am using `HttpInterceptor` for user token.

**User Service**

```
saveUser(user: Users) {
    const body: Users = {
      userName: user.userName,
      userPassword: user.userPassword,
      userEmail: user.userEmail,
      userFullname: user.userFullname,
      userFirstname:user.userFullname,
      userLastname:user.userFullname,
      userType:user.userType,
      userPhone :user.userPhone,
      userBio :user.userBio
    }

    return this.http.post(this.rootUrl + '/api/Users/saveUser', body);
  }
```

**Request Screenshot**

[image]

**Error Screenshot**

[image]

**Api code**

```
[Route("api/Users/saveUsers")]
[ResponseType(typeof(User))]
public IHttpActionResult PostUser([FromBody] User user)
{
  db.Users.Add(user);
  db.SaveChanges();
  return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = user.UserID }, user);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see that your API url when you making request is wrong

```
localhost:57286//api/Users/saveUsers
```

So you should change your code to

```
  return this.http.post(this.rootUrl + 'api/Users/saveUsers', body);
```

And in your controller you should have HttpPost like this

If you are using ASP.Net you have to change to this

```
[HttpPost)]
[Route("api/Users/saveUsers")]
[ResponseType(typeof(User))]
```

And in ASP.Net Core

```
[HttpPost("api/Users/saveUsers")]
[ResponseType(typeof(User))]
```

So you can remove Route and replace with HttpPost

Please let me know if you still have problem

Comment: Thanks for correction,i have correct the url issue but [HttpPost("api/Users/saveUsers")] is not working

Comment: Error Message : httpgetattribute does not contain a constructor

Comment: Are you using ASP.Net Core or ASP.Net ?

Comment: I am using asp.net web api 2

Comment: Then check my answer again

Comment: It is working with postman but when i call the same function from front it gives me error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193558/discussion-between-tony-ngo-and-muhammad-rashid).